# Removing pages from PDF doesn't reduce size

Tags: pdf, compression, editing

Have a PDF (**20MB**) with 10 pages.

I'd like to cut the PDF in two parts of less than ~12MB (mail sending limit).

- created `part1.pdf` with pages 1-5  (6 to 10 removed)
- created `part2.pdf` with pages 6-10 (1 to 5 removed)

But the two PDFs are still ~**19.5MB** each!

- Even with only 1 page, the PDF still takes the same.

Tried various tools (PDF studio, PDF Editor, Xournal, PDF Mod), all yield the same heavy result.

My guess is some embedded data (font, ...?) remain in each of these derived PDFs from the 10 pages one.

- Where should I look in the PDF to remove some likely unnecessary data?
- Any tip apreciated

Comment: You can try Nitro PDF or split them using Winrar

Comment: Nitro is Windows only (using Linux). WinRAR: I'm afraid the receiving people may not be able to pick up the pieces!

Answer (score 1):

First, open the PDF file that you want to break into different parts. Click on the Tools pane, Pages panel and select the Split Document command. The Split Document dialog allows you to control the split by the number of pages in a file, file size, or by top-level bookmarks.

Comment: Which tool are we talking about to open the file/split?

Answer (score 0):

[PDFsam](http://www.pdfsam.org/) works on Linux and, when splitting a PDF file automatically tries to optimize the result, removing unused resources like shared images or fonts.
Here is a simple tutorial on [how to split PDF files](http://www.pdfsam.org/pdf-split/) using PDFsam.

If that doesn't work you could try to compress the resulting files with [compress PDF task](https://www.sejda.com/compress-pdf) in Sejda but be aware that it could decrease images quality.